# Rank SQL for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this output from my 1st query, and i wont know the rank row for each session over contactID and service ID.

Each ContactID + ServiceID need group to obtain rank over sessionID by createdDate Desc.

My data:

[image]

My query

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceID, ContactID , SESSIONID ORDER BY [Created] DESC) AS rn1,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceID, ContactID , SESSIONID ORDER BY [Created] DESC) AS rn2,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceID, ContactID , SESSIONID ORDER BY [Created] DESC) AS rn3 
 FROM #TABLE
```

My output its not what I need.

I need some like this:

[image]

Comment: if you first calculate max createdate per session, you can dense_rank on that. Something like: `select dense_rank() over(partition by contactid, serviceid order by mx DESC), * from (select *, max(createddate) over(partition by contactid, serviceid, sessionid) AS mx from yourtable) x`

Comment: @siggemannen Seems that `sessionID` is monotonically increasing anyway, soit comes to the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, i guess, but i gave the poster benefit of a doubt, you never know how rest of the data looks! Actually, he didn't say how to handle overlapping dates between sessions either. Oh well

Comment: Please don't use images, use tabular text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the date is irrelevant to the calculation, you just want `DENSE_RANK` sorted by sessionID

```sql
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceID, ContactID ORDER BY SESSIONID DESC) AS Rank
```